# Accidentally ran the command mv lib/* /usr/lib/* and now many commands like "sudo" and "java" don't work anymore

Tags: 18.04, java, sudo, mv

```
mv lib/* /usr/lib/*
```

I ran this to move all my files in lib into /usr/lib directory it did move them but up with the above mentioned errors. I was in /home/appu/ directory when I ran the command.
there were only three directories before I ran this command but after running it, it created a directory named x86_64-linux-gnu with some pre existing files and the files I intended to move
sudo command produces following: `sudo: error while loading shared libraries: libsudo_util.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Edit: I'm going to reinstall it now.

Comment: I was in /home/appu/

Comment: Added the info in question as you asked

Comment: There's no `lib` in $HOME by default. Are you sure you were in `/home/appu`? What is the output of `type -a sudo java`?

Comment: There was a lib directory in my /home/directory which I created yesterday. sudo is usr/bin/sudo, type: java not found

Comment: sudo command produces this error:  sudo: error while loading shared libraries: libsudo_util.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Did you run `mv /usr/lib/* lib/*` in an attempt to recover files?

Comment: It's actually a cloud server :(

Comment: And there were only three directories before I ran this command but after running it, it created a directory named x86_64-linux-gnu with some pre existing files and the files I intended to move

Comment: It looks like you used `mv /lib/* /usr/lib/*` note the `/` before the first lib in the command. `/lib` is at the root of the folder tree and is part of the system folders. That folder has a folder named `x86_64-linux-gnu`.

Comment: /lib still has the directory named x86_64-linux-gnu.. and I used the command specified in the question

Comment: Are you saying that /usr/lib now contains only four subdirectories? If so, much of your system is destroyed, and reinstall is your only option.

Comment: It actually had just three before I ran this command

Comment: The folder `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` exist in my healthy system, so it seems to be normal. You moved the files you intended to move and all other files and subfolders of `/usr/lib` into this folder. Take a look at `man mv` and think about what expansion does with the command you used. You should never use a wildcard in the destination of the `mv`-command.

Comment: You have stirred your system with a `root` stick. Try to backup your files, or copy them to a USB stick, then REINSTALL.